# Do you have mixed feelings "on" something or "about" something?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

It seems to me that both the forms are used but I don't know if they have the same meaning or not.

Comment: I always say (American English) that I have _feelings **about** something_, never **on** something. But there may be dialects that use "on".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no rule here, but "mixed feelings about" is far and away the most commonly used expression. Check out this google [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mixed%20feelings%20for,%20mixed%20feelings%20about,%20mixed%20feelings%20on,%20mixed%20feelings%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) graph for the following four constructions using "mixed feelings + preposition":

- Mixed feelings for
- Mixed feelings on
- Mixed feelings about
- Mixed feelings to

[image]

While all four constructions register in google's library, "mixed feelings about" is the one most people will recognize. As for differences between the two examples you've provided, I can see no clear distinction. Furthermore, if you use "mixed feelings" with another preposition, chances are people will understand that you mean "mixed feelings about."

Answer (score 4):

I use ''mixed feelings about something'' because it tells me that I am have feelings for something. ''On'' would be better used if you were saying ''mixed feelings on the topic of -something-''. Mostly I prefer about for the way it sounds. It just sounds better.